# Query Regarding Maven Aspectj

Tags: maven, aspectj, instrumentation

I’m using AspectJ in my project. My project is based on Maven. 
I’m able to successfully compile the .aj file and when I try to run the testcase using maven my aspects are working fine.

But when I start executing the program from command prompt (eg.. java <*.jar>) my aspects are not working. Is it necessary to set any Java JVM option for my aspect to execute.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Have you added the correct jar's into your classpath to run the project ?